# How to run chrome in app mode without window frame?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, kiosk

I would like to run chrome in app mode without using a windows frame and the title bar?

At the moment I start chrome in this way: `chrome.exe --app=http://url.com --app-shell-host-windows-bounds`. That works but there is still the window frame with the title frame visible. The user should not have the opportunity to close, maximize or minimize the chrome window. 
Furthermore I want to have special size for the chrome browser. But the switch `--app-shell-host-windows-bounds` does not have any effect with the size e.g. 600x1024 or 1024x600.

How can change the size of the browser window with this switch?

Answer (score 1):

Developers have madness if allow "The user should not have the opportunity to close, maximize or minimize the chrome window. ". But it possible do it with external tools(i don't will say how).

You can set size and position with this command line:

```
--window-size=1024,600
--window-position=600,600
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates) more info.

[Chromium command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Did you try this switch? I'm afraid but they are not working.

Comment: @Irgendw Pointer Working but need fully exit Chrome before try it. Switch `--chrome-frame` don't work for me. With this switch should work even with running Chrome, if i understand correctly from previous link. Can you show your full command line?

Comment: That works neither! `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --app=http://www.sta
ckoverflow.com --windows-size=800,600`

Comment: @Irgendw Pointer If link contain spaces you need add quotes.  `chrome.exe --app="http://www.sta ckoverflow.com" --windows-size=800,600`

Comment: There are no spaces, thats a copy paste error. But the windows-size is always the same.

Comment: @Irgendw Pointer Did you try add switch `--user-data-dir` or `--chrome-frame` from previous link? If this don't work only way make page with javascript  with [button for popup window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeto) (Chrome  block all popups by default). But i repeat `--window-size=` work on my Windows 7 in Chrome portable and SRWare Iron.

Comment: worked on normal windows thx! but unfortunately didnt work with --kiosk, I had to use this trick http://askubuntu.com/a/320660/46437

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to start chrome without any bar visible (title, tools, url...) on my left screen:

```
@echo off

set CHROME_EXE=c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

set CHROME_SETTINGS=
set CHROME_SETTINGS=%CHROME_SETTINGS% --window-position=-1928,-30
set CHROME_SETTINGS=%CHROME_SETTINGS% --window-size=1936,1050
set CHROME_SETTINGS=%CHROME_SETTINGS% --app=http://10.67.213.20:8080/left.html

start "" "%CHROME_EXE%" %CHROME_SETTINGS%
```